# invalid use of non-static member function (while loop/no classes/wget popen)

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, wget, popen

Disclaimer: i have no clue what i'm doing & trying to google my way through this;

Compiler Error;

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int sourcePull()’:
main.cpp:35:28: error: invalid use of non-static member function
   system(command.c_str + source);
                          ^
```

Source Function;

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int sourcePull()
{
string source;
string command;
command = "wget -np -a source.log ";

ifstream sourceFile ("sources.txt");
if (sourceFile.is_open())
{
    while (sourceFile.good())
    {
        while (sourceFile >> source)
        {
            //system(command.c_str + source);
            FILE* file = popen(command.c_str + source, "r");
        }
        sourceFile.close();
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

not sure how "source" would be a member function when I have no classes for it to be a member of.

Have tried making "source" a pointer (*source), referencing source (&source), no dice...

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean

```
FILE* file = popen((command.c_str() + source).c_str(), "r");
                               ^^^^
```